# How to publish a PromotionSourceRule through Impex?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have used the below `impEx` to create a coupon based promotion rule. The rule gets created successfully but the promotion modules doesn't get deployed to it.

```
INSERT_UPDATE PromotionSourceRule;code[unique=true];priority;maxAllowedRuns;stackable[default=false];ruleGroup(code);conditions;actions;website(Identifier)[default=$defaultPromoGrp];status(code)[default=$defaultRuleStatus];excludeFromStorefrontDisplay[default=false]

"#% beforeEach:
if(de.hybris.platform.personalizationsampledataaddon.util.CxAddOnSampleDataUtils.isPromotionSourceRuleUnmodifiable(line.get(new Integer(1)))){
    line.clear();
}";
"#% afterEach: de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean(""ruleEngineSystemSetup"").registerSourceRuleForDeployment(impex.getLastImportedItem(), new String[]{$promotionModule, $promotionPreviewModule});"
;coupon_code_20_percentage_cart_discount;25;1;true;couponPromotionRuleGroup;"[{""definitionId"":""y_qualifying_coupons"",""parameters"":{""coupons"":{""uuid"":""COUPON20"",""type"":""List(ItemType(AbstractCoupon))"",""value"":[""COUPON20""]}},""children"":[]}]";"[{""definitionId"":""y_order_percentage_discount"",""parameters"":{""value"":{""uuid"":""20"",""type"":""java.math.BigDecimal"",""value"":20}}}]";;;
```

Answer (score 0):

did you do the import through the hac or as part of a system init/update?

The logic in the RuleEngineSystemSetup only works in the context of a system initialization or system update. 
If you look at the default implementation you will see:

```
public class DefaultRuleEngineSystemSetup extends AbstractEventListener<AfterInitializationEndEvent>
```

so during the impex and the call to `registerSourceRuleForDeployment` the rules are only registered for publication and once the `AfterInitializationEndEvent` is fired (by the platform after an init/update) the collected rules are published.

If you run this script in the context of the hac you could use beanshell code to either invoke one of the regular `RuleEngineService` methods to initialize your module(s) or you could try to invoke the `DefaultRuleEngineSystemSetup.onEvent(final AfterInitializationEndEvent event)` method passing in a "fake" non-null event to trigger the logic inside the system setup class (it requires a non-null event for logging which event came in I believe, but other than that the event is not used)
The last thing I haven't tried, both requires some more scripting in your impex script.

Hope this helps,
Sebastian

Comment: I did not initialize/update the system but had run the impex directly on hac. How should i proceed now?

Comment: I added something to my answer, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The below impex will be used to compile and publish the promotion rules

```
$defaultPromoGrp = <promo-group>
$promotionSourceRulesQuery="select {psr.pk} from {PromotionSourceRule as psr},{PromotionGroup as pg} where {psr.code} in ('<Promotion Code with comma separated>') and {pg.Identifier}='$defaultPromoGrp' and {psr.website}={pg.pk}"

"#%groovy% ruleCompilerService = spring.getBean('ruleCompilerService');

platformRuleEngineService = spring.getBean('platformRuleEngineService');

flexibleSearchService = spring.getBean('flexibleSearchService');

List sourceRules = flexibleSearchService.search($promotionSourceRulesQuery).getResult();

spring.getBean('ruleMaintenanceService').compileAndPublishRules(sourceRules, ""promotions-module"", false);
";
```